# Raw Read Error Rate растёт SSD

Tags: windows, ssd

Постоянно растёт Raw Read Error Rate, на практически новом SSD, модель Kingston SSD V300 60GB.Нормально ли это?

Comment: Нет, конечно же.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я знаю что это не хорошо (для HDD), но например Seagate указывает в данном параметре реальное количество внутренних ошибок которые возникают постоянно на любом HDD, а вот WD эти данные не отображает, у меня постоянно 0, хотя на Seagate это значение очень большое, диск намного старше WD, и работает просто отлично, так я думаю может и у Kingston так же как и у Seagate? Некоторые владельцы данной модели также говорили о росте данного параметра... Но как говорится хочется перестраховаться и уточнить)

Comment: Вот как раз для HDD с его механикой это нормально. А сектора SSD должны читаться с первого раза.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Что можете посоветовать? Диск покупал в другом городе ехать ради него не охота... Может есть какое-то решение? Сейчас попробую сделать ATA Security Erase, затем заново установлю ОС, диск проработал 15 часов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо! Диск действительно был бракованный!